# Differentiation Theorem

Tags: integration, derivatives

Assume that a function $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ w.r.t. an increasing function $g$, that $f$ is continuous at $c\in[a,b]$ and that $g$ is differentiable at $c$. Then the function defined by $F(x)=\int_a^xfdg$ ($x\in[a,b]$) is defferentiable at $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)g'(c)$.

I tried to prove this as follows.

For $h>0$ with $c+h\in[a,b]$, let $M_h=\sup\{f(x):x\in[c,c+h]\}$ and $m_h=\inf\{f(x):x\in[c,c+h]\}$. Then we have
$$
m_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}\le \frac{1}{h}\int_c^{c+h}fdg\le M_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}.
$$
Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $g$ has a derivative at $c$, it follows that $\lim_{h\to0+}M_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0+}m_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}=f(c)g'(c)$.

A similar relation holds if $h<0$. Hence, $F'(c)=f(c)g'(c)$.

Does there exist any error in the above argument? Or, someone can give a much simpler proof. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe a silly question: "Then we have
$$
m_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}\le \int_c^{c+h}fdg\le M_h\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}.\hbox{"}
$$, why do we?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin There's a division by $h$ missing in the middle term of the chain of inequalities. When that is fixed, the inequalities hold by the monotonicity of the integral, which holds since $g$ is increasing.